# Converter objeto em json no php

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando cria uma classe que salve objetos do tipo `Conta` em um arquivo json, porém, na hora de salvar no arquivo, as informações do objeto não são salvas, fica apenas isso:

> [[],{}]

Minha classe que está lendo e salvando no json é:

```
class JSONCustom {

    private $list = null;
    private $jsonFile = "teste.json";

    public function __construct() {
        if (file_exists($this->jsonFile)) {

            $string = file_get_contents($this->jsonFile);
            $json = json_decode($string, true);
            $this->list = $json;
        } else {
            $this->list = Array();
        }
    }

    public function getList() {

        return $this->list;
    }

    public function add($item) {
        //$jsonObject = get_object_vars($item);
        $this->list[] = $item;
        $this->save();
    }

    private function save() {
        if ($this->list != null) {
            $string = json_encode($this->list);
            file_put_contents($this->jsonFile, $string);
        }
    }
}

$agencia = new JSONCustom();

$conta = new Corrente(123, "teste", 3.10);
$agencia->add($conta);

var_dump($agencia->getList());
```

A classe Corrente:

```
class Corrente extends Conta{
    private $tarifaManutencao = 12.5;

    public function __construct($num, $prop, $saldo){
        parent::__construct($num, $prop, $saldo);
    }

    public function getTipoconta(){
        return "Corrente";
    }

    public function listarDados(){
        return parent::listarDados().
        "\nTipo de Conta: ".$this->getTipoconta().
        /* "\nTarifa de Manutencao: ".$this->tarifaManutencao; */
        "\nTarifa de Manutencao: ".CalcularFloat::formatarMoeda($this->tarifaManutencao);
    }

    public function cobrarTarifa(){
        if($this->getSaldo() < $this->tarifaManutencao){
            $this->habilitarPermissoesEspeciais();
            $this->sacar($this->tarifaManutencao);
            $this->desabilitarPermissoesEspeciais();
        }else{
            $this->sacar($this->tarifaManutencao);
        }
    }

    protected function setTarifaManutencao($novaTarifa){
        $this->tarifaManutencao = $novaTarifa;
    }
}
```

E minha classe abstrata Conta:

```
abstract class Conta{
    private $numero;
    private $proprietario;
    private $saldo;
    private $permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas = false;

    public function __construct($num, $prop,$saldo){
        if($num < 0){
            throw new ExcecaoNumeroInvalido("Numero da conta nao pode ser negativo.");
        }else if($saldo < 0){
            throw new ExcecaoValorNegativo("Saldo nao pode ser negativo.");
        }
        $this->numero = $num;
        $this->proprietario = $prop;
        $this->saldo = $saldo;
    }

    public function getNumero(){
        return $this->numero;
    }

    public function getProprietario(){
        return $this->proprietario;
    }

    public function getSaldo(){
        return $this->saldo;
    }

    public function listarDados(){
        return "Numero: ".$this->numero.
        "\nNome: ".$this->proprietario.
        /* "\nSaldo: ".$this->getSaldo(); */
        "\nSaldo: ".CalcularFloat::formatarMoeda($this->getSaldo());
    }

    protected function permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas(){
        return $this->permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas;
    }

    public function habilitarPermissoesEspeciais(){
        $this->permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas = true;
    }

    public function desabilitarPermissoesEspeciais(){
        $this->permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas = false;
    }

    protected function verificarCondicoesParaSaque($valor){
        if ($valor < 0){
            throw new ExcecaoValorNegativo("Valor de saque nao pode ser negativo.");
        }else if($valor > $this->saldo && !$this->permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas()){
            throw new ExcecaoSaqueInvalido("Sem saldo suficiente para este valor saque.");
        }
    }

    public function sacar($valor){
        $this->verificarCondicoesParaSaque($valor);
        $this->saldo = CalcularFloat::subtrair($this->saldo, $valor);
    }

    public function depositar($valor){
        if($valor < 0){
            throw new ExcecaoValorNegativo("Valor de deposito nao pode ser negativo.");
        }
        $this->saldo = CalcularFloat::somar($this->saldo, $valor);
    }

    public abstract function getTipoconta();
}
```

Ao executar um `var_dump($agencia->getList());` o resultado retorna o objeto normalmente:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  1 => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  2 => 
    object(Corrente)[2]
      private 'tarifaManutencao' => float 12.5
      private 'numero' (Conta) => int 123
      private 'proprietario' (Conta) => string 'teste' (length=5)
      private 'saldo' (Conta) => float 3.1
      private 'permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas' (Conta) => boolean false
```

Porém ao converter o array em json  em `$string = json_encode($this->list);` o array não é convertido e salva apenas o citado no começo da questão.

Comment: Já usou o `print_r` para ver se o array é exibido corretamente?

Comment: @Gilsones sim, olha o resultado do `var_dump` no final da pergunta. O array está dessa forma.

Comment: É que em um vc usou `$agencia->getList()` e no outro `$this->list`. Acho importante fazer o var_dump no mesmo local onde está tentando usar o json_encode. Aliás, usa o `print_r` onde está o json_encode. Pelo menos pra mim é mais amigável. depois coloca também no final do post.

Comment: isso acontece porque são objetos privados. coloque eles como "public"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consegui obter todos os atributos da minha classe `Corrente` e os herdados da classe `Conta`, adicionando a interface [**JsonSerialize**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) em ambas as classes, conforme a [**referência do SOen**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20117815/5524514) citada pelo @rray.

Essa interface obriga a implementar o método `jsonSerialize()` que adicionei na classe `Conta`:

```
public function jsonSerialize() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
```

E na classe `Corrente` eu fiz o mesmo, porém, fazendo uma chamada do `jsonSerialize()` da classe mãe, e depois unindo os arrays resultante das duas classes, contendo todos os atributos das duas classes:

```
public function jsonSerialize() {
    $vars = array_merge(get_object_vars($this),parent::jsonSerialize());
    return $vars;
}
```

Agora o objeto está sendo salvo completo, vejam a saída do `print_r`:

```
[
  {
    "tarifaManutencao": 12.5,
    "numero": 123,
    "proprietario": "teste",
    "saldo": 3.1,
    "permissoesEspeciaisHabilitadas": false
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Membros privados não são convertidos por `json_encode()` sua classe nesse caso pode implementar um método que obtém todas as 'variáveis' da classe e retornar um json.

Exemplo que reproduz o erro:

```
class Pessoa {
    private $id = 99;
    private $nome = 'teste';
    private $idade = 20;
}

echo json_encode(new Pessoa());
```

Exemplo que funciona:

```
class Pessoa {
    private $id = 99;
    private $nome = 'teste';
    private $idade = 20;

    function serialize(){
        return json_encode(get_object_vars ($this));
    }   
}

$p = new Pessoa();
echo json_encode($p->serialize());
```

**Referência**

[PHP json_encode class private members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7005860/1342547)

Comment: Tem como eu interceptar isso semelhante ao to_string() do java?

Comment: Muito legal @rray sua resposta e solução, não conhecia essa solução utilizando `get_object_vars`. +1

Comment: Pelo que entendi do link do SOen que você adicionou(sou pessimo em ingles hhehe), se implementar a interface `JsonSerializable` e a função de mesmo nome, eu só precisaria mudar a classe do objeto CORRENTE, é isso mesmo?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe, da sim, você tornar `serialize()` um método privado e na implementação de `toString()` chamar ele, para acionar ele fica assim: `$p = new Pessoa(); echo $p;`, dessa forma o ´codigo me parece obscuro.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe, correto, lembrando que essa interface está disponível a partir da versão 5.4, ai você faz a implementação do que deseja expor como json, pode usar `get_object_vars()`.

Comment: Descobri um problema, ao usar isso, não traz os atributos da classe Conta, da qual a classe Corrente está herdando. Creio ser outra pergunta esse tema ne?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe to pesando aqui ... esse código vc jogou na classe `Conta` ?

Comment: Consegui resolver seguindo sua dica do `get_object_vars` e da raferencia que postou, vou postar o que fiz.

Answer (score 2):

Já passei por esse problema e encontrei essa solução:

```
    if ($_GET['tipo'] == 'GET_OBJECT'){ 
        header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        $object = $_GET['object'];
        $objectController = new ObjectController();
        $objects = $objectController->getObjects($param);
        $lista_json = array("objects_array" => array());

        foreach($objects as $object){
            $obj = array (
                "attribute1" => $object->getAttribute()
            );

            array_push($lista_json["objects_array"], $obj);
        }
        echo json_encode($lista_json);
    }
```

Espero que seja a solução para seu problema também, apesar do código estar completamente diferente. Verifico inclusive antes do primeiro IF qual é o método, se foi um GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, mas essa parte já não é tão importante para o seu problema.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

    // Continuação do código, incluindo o código mencionado acima

}
```

Comment: ObjectController é uma classe sua customizada ou é do php mesmo?

Comment: Uma classe customizada que realiza operações de CRUD, além de SELECT, com objetos de um determinado tipo.