# Como converter array de objetos PHP para JSON

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando aprender AngularJS e hoje tenho uma aplicação PHP5, porém não estou utilizando RESTful. Para fins de testes quero executar a minha consulta e preencher uma tabela com o resultado utilizando o AngularJS.
O meu problema é que eu executo a pesquisa dentro da classe através do método que criei, e ele retorna obviamente um array com cada objeto e suas propriedades conforme a consulta. Dei uma pesquisada e tentei utilizar a seguinte linha para converter meu array para JSON e utilizar o AngularJS, mas o meu retorno está sendo vazio.

```
$cervejas = new Cerveja();
$lista = $tt->listar();
echo json_encode($lista);
```

Porém assim não consegui imprimir o meu array de objetos. 
PS: se eu der um

```
print_r ($lista);
```

O array está com o conteúdo.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Cerveja Object ( [id:Cerveja:private] => 2 [nomeCerveja:Cerveja:private] => Cerveja 1 ) 
[1] => Cerveja Object ( [id:Cerveja:private] => 3 [nomeCerveja:Cerveja:private] => Cerveja 2 ) 
[2] => Cerveja Object ( [id:Cerveja:private] => 6 [nomeCerveja:Cerveja:private] => Cerveja 3 ) 
)
```

Comment: Pode mostrar a o retorno de `$lista`? `$beras` está ali pq hj é sexta? xD

Comment: @rray adicionei o resultado. [off]Todos exemplos ficam melhor com cerveja[/off]

Comment: Atributos private não são convertido no json, já tem um pergunta sobre isso já acho ela.

Comment: Acho que resolve, [Converter objeto em json no php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97415/91)

Comment: @rray conheço essa pergunta ai. :p