# Array PHP para Json

Tags: php, jquery, json

eu tenho essa consulta, eu preciso exibir cada coluna em uma div do HTML. Bom, preciso retornar os dados num array PHP, passar esse array php para um array em JS para conseguir manipular e exibir eles nas suas respectivas divs, a consulta ta funcionando perfeitamente, mas como passo isso pro Jquery? Preciso usar Json, certo? Eu tentei usar um Json encode, mas não funcionou.

```
    <?php

$equipe1 = $_POST['equipe1'];//Pega o Nome da equipe
$equipe2 = $_POST ['equipe2'];//Pega o Nome da equipe
$dificuldade = $_POST ['dificuldade'];//Define a dificuldade das perguntas que seram selecionadas
$rodada = $_POST ['rodada'];//Número de perguntas que serão retornadas

echo $equipe1;
echo $equipe2;

switch ($dificuldade) {
  case '1':
    $dificuldade = "Facil";
    break;
  case '2':
    $dificuldade = "Medio";
    break;
  case '3':
    $dificuldade = "Dificil";
    break;
}

switch ($rodada) {
  case '1':
    $rodada = "10";
    break;
  case '2':
    $rodada = "15";
    break;
  case '3':
    $rodada = "20";
    break;
}
    try{
     $conexao = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=teocratico; charset=utf8","root","");
     } catch (PDOException $erro){
       echo $erro->getmessage();
       //header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
     }


$consulta = $conexao -> query ("SELECT id_pergunta, pergunta, resposta, desafio FROM perguntas
           where dificuldade ='$dificuldade' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT $rodada ");

// Mostrando a Consulta
$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   while($row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo  $row['id_pergunta']. ' - '. $row['pergunta'] . ' - ' . $row['resposta'] .' - '. $row ['desafio'].' <BR /> ';
  }


?>
```

Comment: Faça $response = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) e depois $json = json_enconde($reponse) que irá funcionar. Depois é só dar um echo na variável $json e usar no JavaScript.

Comment: admito que não tinha pesquisado haha, essa pergunta pode ser considerada duplicada desta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117739/como-converter-array-de-objetos-php-para-json que já e duplicada desta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97415/converter-objeto-em-json-no-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou aproveitar que estou com a mão na massa para explicar para você.

Quando você tem um array em `php` nesse formato (executando um `var_dump($array)` no servidor):

> object(stdClass)#6394 (59) { ["id_customer"]=> string(1) "1"
>   ["fk_customer_civilstatus"]=> string(1) "1" ["hashed_id"]=> string(6)
>   "xxxxxx" ["name"]=> string(17) "Marcelo" ["cpf"]=> NULL
>   ["phone"]=> string(15) "" ["email"]=> string(28)
>   "mb@mail.com" ["password"]=> string(60)
>   "" ["gender"]=> string(1) "M" ["birthdate"]=> string(10)
>   "0000-00-00" ["id_google"]=> NULL ["id_facebook"]=> NULL
>   ["avatar_url"]=> NULL ["changekey"]=> NULL ["last_access"]=>
>   string(19) "2017-01-25 02:45:17" ["created_at"]=> NULL
>   ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["idusuario"]=> string(6) "xxxxxx"
>   ["id_address"]=> string(1) "1" ["postal_code"]=> string(9) "00000-000"
>   ["country"]=> string(6) "Brasil" ["street"]=> string(25) "" ["state"]=> string(2) "SP" ["city"]=> string(10) "São
>   Paulo" ["number"]=> string(2) "99" ["district"]=> string(12) "" ["complement"]=> string(0) "" ["id_creditcard"]=> NULL
>   ["creditcard"]=> NULL ["total_price"]=> string(4) "1490"
>   ["id_coupons"]=> NULL ["coupon_name"]=> NULL ["coupon_code"]=> NULL
>   ["discount"]=> NULL ["duration_months"]=> NULL ["start_date"]=> NULL
>   ["end_date"]=> NULL ["id_sales_order_item"]=> string(1) "1"
>   ["fk_sales_order"]=> string(1) "1" ["fk_product"]=> string(2) "22"
>   ["contract_sl_id"]=> NULL ["fk_sales_order_item_status"]=> string(1)
>   "1" ["fk_sales_order_item_cancellation"]=> NULL ["fk_shipping"]=> NULL
>   ["original_unit_price"]=> string(4) "1490" ["final_unit_price"]=>
>   string(4) "1490" ["trial_start"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
>   ["trial_end"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["active_from"]=>
>   NULL ["active_until"]=> NULL ["id_subscription_status_type"]=>
>   string(1) "3" ["status"]=> string(9) "congelado"
>   ["id_payment_method"]=> NULL ["method"]=> NULL
>   ["id_sales_order_item_cancellation"]=> NULL ["request_date"]=> NULL
>   ["cancellation_date"]=> NULL ["reason"]=> NULL }

Ao alterar o formato de retorno executando: `json_encode($array)` você obtêm:

> {"id_customer":"1","fk_customer_civilstatus":"1","hashed_id":"xxxxxx","name":"Marcelo","cpf":null,"phone":"","email":"mb@mail.com","password":"","gender":"M","birthdate":"0000-00-00","id_google":null,"id_facebook":null,"avatar_url":null,"changekey":null,"last_access":"2017-01-25
>   02:45:17","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"idusuario":"7Z2PZ6","id_address":"1","postal_code":"00000-000","country":"Brasil","street":"","state":"SP","city":"S\u00e3o
>   Paulo","number":"99","district":"","complement":"","id_creditcard":null,"creditcard":null,"total_price":"1490","id_coupons":null,"coupon_name":null,"coupon_code":null,"discount":null,"duration_months":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"id_sales_order_item":"1","fk_sales_order":"1","fk_product":"22","contract_sl_id":null,"fk_sales_order_item_status":"1","fk_sales_order_item_cancellation":null,"fk_shipping":null,"original_unit_price":"1490","final_unit_price":"1490","trial_start":"0000-00-00
>   00:00:00","trial_end":"0000-00-00
>   00:00:00","active_from":null,"active_until":null,"id_subscription_status_type":"3","status":"congelado","id_payment_method":null,"method":null,"id_sales_order_item_cancellation":null,"request_date":null,"cancellation_date":null,"reason":null}

Verifique que este segundo formato é um `json` valido ([ferramenta online que verifica se um json é valido](http://jsonlint.com/), jogue a string acima e teste).

Agora na parte do `client-side` que requisita esta consulta você pode montar um script que trabalhe com `ajax` dessa forma:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "/api/user/",
  type: "POST",
  data: data,
  success: function(returnjson) {
    alert(returnjson.id_customer);
  },
  error: function(returnjson) {
    if (returnjson.status == 500) {
      alert("Erro interno do servidor, tente novamente ou entre em contato com o suporte técnico.");
    } else {
      alert(returnjson.responseJSON.msg);
    }
  }
});
```

Dentro do `alert(returnjson.id_customer);` você terá impresso o valor que retornou do seu `json`.

Vale lembrar que no servidor também é importante definir o `header` correto: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

---

No seu caso você pode trabalhar sua pagina `php` da seguinte maneira:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$equipe1 = $_POST['equipe1'];//Pega o Nome da equipe
$equipe2 = $_POST ['equipe2'];//Pega o Nome da equipe
$dificuldade = $_POST ['dificuldade'];//Define a dificuldade das perguntas que seram selecionadas
$rodada = $_POST ['rodada'];//Número de perguntas que serão retornadas
switch ($dificuldade) {
    case '1':
    $dificuldade = "Facil";
    break;
    case '2':
    $dificuldade = "Medio";
    break;
    case '3':
    $dificuldade = "Dificil";
    break;
}
switch ($rodada) {
    case '1':
    $rodada = "10";
    break;
    case '2':
    $rodada = "15";
    break;
    case '3':
    $rodada = "20";
    break;
}
try{
    $conexao = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=teocratico; charset=utf8","root","");
} catch (PDOException $erro){
    echo $erro->getmessage();
    //header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
}
$consulta = $conexao->query ("SELECT id_pergunta, pergunta, resposta, desafio FROM perguntas
where dificuldade ='$dificuldade' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT $rodada ");
// Mostrando a Consulta
$db_data = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
die(json_encode($db_data));
```

Comment: No momento estou no trabalho, assim que eu chegar em casa eu vou dar uma olhada, Muito obrigado. @marcelobonifazio

Comment: Só uma coisa, porque tem um "die" ali?

Comment: @TiagoSilveira o die garante que o script vai morrer ali, caso tenha mais alguma execução abaixo, ele não chegara

Comment: Veja que também  os `echo` que tinha no começo, se houver qualquer "lixo" que não esteja no formato esperado pelo `json`, o `ajax` simplesmente não vai interpretar como um formato `json` valido

Comment: não ta rolando kkk tipo, eu coloco o json encode, ele me retorna isso {
 "queryString": "SELECT id_pergunta, pergunta, resposta, desafio FROM perguntas\r\nwhere dificuldade ='Facil' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10 "
}, ironicamente é um json válido, mas não com os dados da consulta kkk

Comment: @TiagoSilveira o que não esta rolando e a query, não o json_encode :)

Comment: atualizei o código, veja se agora vai

Comment: FUNCIONOU, CARA, VOCÊ É O MELHOR kkkk

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52559/discussion-between-tiago-silveira-and-marcelo-bonifazio).