# Como listar as propriedades de um objeto no php usando foreach?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, foreach

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
class Usuario{
     private $nome;
     private $profissao;

     function setNome($nome){
         $this->nome = $nome;
     }

     function getNome(){
         return $this->nome;
     }

     function setProfissao($profissao){
         $this->profissao = $profissao;
     }

     function getProfissao(){
         return $this->profissao;
     }
 }
```

Aqui instancio um objeto

```
$user = new Usuario();

$user->setNome('Nome Qualquer');
$user->setProfissao('Profissão Qualquer');
```

Queria saber como posso listar todas as propriedades desse objet usando **foreach**. Eu já sei que existe `get_object_vars` que já faz isso para mim. Porém queria usar o foreach mesmo para essa finalidade. É claro que o exemplo acima é apenas um exemplo simples.

Comment: Esta resposta deve te ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97571/28595

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso ajudaria?

```
<?php
    class MyClass
    {
        public $var1 = 'value 1';
        public $var2 = 'value 2';
        public $var3 = 'value 3';

        protected $protected = 'protected var';
        private   $private   = 'private var';

        function iterateVisible() {
           echo "MyClass::iterateVisible:\n";
           foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
               print "$key => $value\n";
           }
        }
    }

    $class = new MyClass();

    foreach($class as $key => $value) {
        print "$key => $value\n";
    }
    echo "\n";


    $class->iterateVisible();

    ?>
```

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.iterations.php

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar um método para listar os atributos internamente, nada impede de usar um foreach dessa maneira:

```
class Usuario
{
     private $nome;
     private $profissao;

     public function setNome($nome)
     {
         $this->nome = $nome;
         return $this;
     }

     public function setProfissao($profissao)
     {
         $this->profissao = $profissao;
         return $this;
     }

     public function getNome($nome)
     {
         return $this->nome;
     }

     public function getProfissao($profissao)
     {
         return $this->profissao;
     }

     public function getValueByAttributeName($name)
     {

        if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
           return $this->$name;
        }
     }

    public function getValueByMethodName($name)
    {
        $name = $name.'()';

       if (method_exists($this, $name)) {

           return $this->$name;
       }
    }

    public function getAllAttributes()
    {
        $array = array();

        foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
            if (property_exists($this, $key)) {
                 $array[] = array($key => $value);
            }
         } 
         return $array;

    }
}

$usuario = new Usuario;

$usuario->setNome('Nome Qualquer');
$usuario->setProfissao('Profissão Qualquer');
$data = $usuario->getAllAttributes();

echo 'Exemplo de listar tudo: <pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre><br>Exemplo por método:<br>';
echo '--->'.$usuario->getValueByMethodName('getnome');
echo '<br>';
echo '--->'.$usuario->getValueByMethodName('getprofissao');
echo '<br>Exemplo por atributo:<br>';
echo '--->'.$usuario->getValueByAttributeName('nome');
echo '<br>';
echo '--->'.$usuario->getValueByAttributeName('profissao');
```

[**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/ENgRrb)

Comment: Ao executar o código, no final, dispara um warning, é isso mesmo o esperado? veja: https://ideone.com/mdUlpm

Comment: Só uma correção que fiz no meu código, nos métodos get, o parâmetro coloquei equivocadamente

Comment: @diegofm, o problema era por causa do parênteses do método, já alterei blz.

Answer (score 1):

No código que postou, as propriedades estão definidas como privadas.

Para listar essas propriedades teria que criar um método público onde seria então feito o tal do `foreach` e o retorno do resultado.

De outra forma é usar [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) ou [Closure Bind](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php).

Comment: Hum... isso que eu estava imaginando... De fora da classe não é possível então? Só seria caso as propriedades fossem como public?

Comment: @DanielOmine, mesmo que os atributos estejam privados, os métodos são públicos, então isso não interfere numa listagem, somente não dá para chamá-los diretamente.

Comment: @DiChrist usando a classe, o ideal é sempre declarar os métodos como público, quando forem, exemplo: `public function seuMetodo() { ... }`.

Comment: Sim, @IvanFerrer, pensei nisso mas preferi manter o foco no que diz a pergunta. Diz que quer listar as propriedades e não exatamente os métodos.

Comment: Sim, disso eu sei. Os métodos sempre chamo de public. O único jeito de usar o foreach nessa situação seria listando os atributos dentro de um método publico?

Comment: @DiChrist, por padrão os métodos são publicos quando não especificado nas declarações. O que é o seu caso. Mas é uma má prática. A partir do PHP5.4 é emitido um aviso de que é recomendado declarar explicitamente. Tal aviso depende das configurações de log de erro.

Comment: procure por hydrate ou populate.