# Json PHP e Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Estou trabalhando em um projeto pessoal com uma base de dados abertas, e preciso de um arquivo JSON a partir de uma consulta MYSQL, estou faz alguns dias tentando resolver esse problema e estou com muita dificuldade, pois não consigo pegar o nome dos meus dados. Exemplo: Faço uma consulta para listar todos os estados, eu consigo pegar o json com a ID, UF, Região, quando coloco o campo nome, não me retorna nada e da o erro **Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://localhost/teste.php".** Meu objetivo é pegar todos os dados da consulta e retornar um JSON para tratar com GeoCharts.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","3919223","DatasusNew") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_query('SET NAMES utf8;');
$var = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM estados";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $return[] = [ 
        'nome' => $row['nome'],
        'idEstado' => $row['idEstado'],
        'uf' => $row['uf'],
        'regiao' => $row['regiao']

    ];
}
$dbh = null;

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);

?>
```

Alguém já passou por esse problema? Ou alguma dica?

Comment: amigo, só por curiosidade: vi que seu banco se chama datasusnew. eu também desenvolvo pra sistemas do datasus. entra em contato comigo pra gente trocar uma ideia. abraço

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, consegui!! O código final ficou...Obrigado

```
   if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
   {

    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        foreach($row as $key => $col){
           $col_array[$key] = utf8_encode($col);
        }
        $row_array[] =  $col_array;

    }

    echo json_encode($row_array, SON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?> `
```

Está me retornando assim:
**[{"idEstado":"11","nome":"Rondônia","uf":"RO","regiao":"Norte"},**
Agora vou ter que tratar esses dados em JS...Valeu!

Comment: Opa, legal, dessa maneira não conhecia! +1

Answer (score 1):

Faz o seguintes: use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, ele retorna os resultados associados com o nome da tabela, creio que fique algo assim:

```
    <?php

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","3919223","DatasusNew") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
    mysqli_query('SET NAMES utf8;');
        $var = array();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM estados";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $rows = array();
        while($each = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $rows[] = $each;
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($rows);
     ?>
```

Comment: amigo, só por curiosidade: vi que seu banco se chama datasusnew. eu também desenvolvo pra sistemas do datasus. entra em contato comigo pra gente trocar uma ideia. abraço

Comment: Hey, @ItaloRodrigo. O banco de dados é do rapaz que fez a pergunta. Eu só respondi baseado no código dele. Comenta diretamente na pergunta dele.

Comment: foi mal, não prestei atenção

Answer (score 0):

**Resposta:**

```
$lista_json = array("objects_array" => array());
foreach($result as $row){
     $obj = array (
         "nome" => utf8_encode($row['nome']),
         "idEstado" => $row['idEstado'],
         "uf" => utf8_encode($row['uf']),
         "regiao" => utf8_encode($row['regiao'])
     );

     array_push($lista_json["objects_array"], $obj);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($lista_json);
```

Funcionou?

**Referências:**

[Converter objeto em json no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97415/converter-objeto-em-json-no-php/97419#97419)

[PHP: utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php)

Comment: Não deu certo amigo, continua o mesmo problema...

Comment: O campo "nome" é um JSON ou uma String? Como esta no banco de dados?

Comment: O campo "nome" está como varchar... porém agora eu estou conseguindo retornar todos os dados, mas problema é a acentuação, ele está me retornando assim: **[{"idEstado":"11","nome":"Rond\u00f4nia","uf":"RO","regiao":"Norte"}**

Comment: Alterei com a resposta colocando a função `utf8_encode`, funcionou a acentuação amigo?